# Remove connected components from image which have a sum of pixel values < threshold

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

In simple words, this is an example of input available and the corresponding output I want:

```
In: [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
      0 6 6 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
      0 8 9 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
      8 0 0 0 9 9 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 8 8 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      9 9 7 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
      0 6 8 0 0 0 0 3 2 0
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 0
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
```

After binarizing and obtaining labelled image using **cv2.connectedComponents()**:

```
labels: [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
          0 2 2 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
          0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
          2 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 0
          0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 0
          0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          4 4 4 0 0 0 0 0 5 0
          0 4 4 0 0 0 0 5 5 0
          0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 0
          0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
```

From here, I want the following output:

```
Out: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      0 6 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      0 8 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      8 0 0 0 9 9 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 8 8 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      9 9 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      0 6 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
```

There are many connected components present (in this case: 5 components of 8-connectivity). The components (of **In**) which have their sum of pixels < 10 (a threshold) are removed in **Out**.

How do I implement this in C++ (possibly using OpenCV)?

I have already done it on Python using  OpenCV but not able to implement on C++.

This is a part of my Python code, if useful (**labels** is the output of **cv2.connectedComponents()** ):

```
for cnt in range(1, labels.max()+1): 
        idx = np.where(labels.copy() == cnt)
        valMat = In[idx]
        sum_valMat = sum(valMat)
        if sum_valMat > 3000:
            fingerNodes[idx] = 0
```

Input is a simple 2D matrix. This is an example of connected component:

[image]

Comment: Define "blob".  ...

Comment: I have edited the question. I hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Not really. Connectivity has to do with zeros, right? Does diagonal adjacency of non-zero points constitute connection?  Or must a connection be side-to-side?

Comment: Zeros are background. I mean connectivity among all non-zero elements.

Comment: From the image, it appears that diagonals count as connections.  There was no example of that in the original.

Comment: OpenCV is available in C++.  It's not terribly hard to use either.

Comment: Yes, I know. I am not able to code it in C++. I binarized the input image and applied connectedComponentsWithStats(). This gives me labels. I don't know how to code the rest (as I did in Python).

Comment: Is the connectivity only for the immediately adjacent numbers?  Or does it go on to be all things connected given 8-way connectivity?  If it's only the numbers immediately adjacent, I would suggest looking into a 2D Convolution, because it looks like that's what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: (I have edited the question) The connectivity is only for 8-adjacency. I'm sorry I didn't understand how a 2D convolution will help here. FYI: the matrix is actually an image of size 1000x1000 pixels; for simplicity I have explained it using a small 10x10 matrix.

Answer (score 2):

You've already implemented this in Python, so you know how to solve the problem. I guess being able to implement it in C++ is a matter of knowing the library you want to use.

Your Python implementation is very inefficient: you iterate over the labels, and for each label visit each image pixel (`idx = np.where(labels.copy() == cnt)`). This can get really expensive if you have more than a handful of labels.

In the code below, I loop over the image once to accumulate the sum of the image intensities for each of the labels, then once to paint the image with the computed sum (for each pixel with a label, look up the sum for that label), and then one more time to threshold this image. This thresholded image I then use as a mask to set to 0 the pixels in the input image that you don't want to keep.

I use [DIPlib](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib) here. Though I'm sure you can replicate this using OpenCV in some way if you really want to use it.

```
#include "diplib.h"
#include "dipviewer.h"
#include "diplib/file_io.h"
#include "diplib/regions.h"
#include "diplib/measurement.h"

int main() {
   // Create a test image with similar properties to your example
   dip::Image input = -dip::ImageReadICS( "/Users/cris/newdip/examples/cermet.ics" );
   input.At( input < 120 ) = 0;
   // Display
   dip::viewer::ShowSimple( input, "input image" );
   // Threshold and label
   dip::Image label = dip::Label( input > 0 );
   // Obtain sum of pixels per label
   dip::MeasurementTool measurementTool;
   auto msr = measurementTool.Measure( label, input, { "Mass" } );
   // Paint each label with the measured value
   dip::Image feature = dip::ObjectToMeasurement( label, msr[ "Mass" ] );
   // Create output as a copy of the input, with low feature values set to 0
   dip::Image output = input.Copy();
   output.At( feature < 100000 ) = 0;
   // Display
   dip::viewer::ShowSimple( output, "output image" );
   dip::viewer::Spin();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

You are right, I know the functions to be used too, but I just can't figure out how to code it (I'm new to C++). 

This is exactly what I want, except that I'd prefer to use OpenCV. This is only a small part of a bigger code which uses OpenCV. I'll use your answer, it may help me :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to stick with opencv, you can use `cv::calcHist`  to count the number of occurrences of each label, and filrerout values which corresponds to bin values smaller than 10.
The resulting labeld image should then be binarized, and element-wise multiplied by the source in order to get you desired result.

Comment: I was trying to code it in C or C++, and got stuck there (I could easily do it in Python cuz it's simple)